What does "pivot" refer to?
A counsel found J. Robert Oppenheimer’s picture in a Time magazine with Lewis Strauss
on the cover. The caption, read by a Senate Aide, was Oppenheimer’s quote:
“J. Robert Oppenheimer, Strauss fought and the US won,” reminding Oppenheimer
of his previous statement:

Strauss: We needed to pivot.
Sentae Aide: But how would you know what Time magazine's gonna write?
Strauss: Henry Luce is a friend.

In the conversation, Strauss says “We needed to pivot,” but it’s unclear what he
means. ‘Pivot’ could imply a policy change, a messaging shift, or a strategic move.
What does "pivot" refer to?

(FWIW, I think that this use of ‘pivot’ is anachronistic — that the metaphorical meaning didn't become popular until long after when the movie is set.)

Its not a quote from Oppenheimer, its just a caption from the magazine, essentially an editorial comment.
You can see the picture in the Time Vault.  The caption is even 'fought him':

The Time article and caption suggests that Strauss fighting Oppenheimer, primarily over the decision the build a hydrogen bomb, was justified and good for the USA.
The scene suggests that his friendship with Henry Luce, founder of the magazine, lead to the article that was favorable for Strauss.  The pivot was to embrace his role of standing up to Oppenheimer

Or, perhaps, the "pivot" was the decision to focus on building hydrogen bombs which was the topic where Strauss clashed with Oppenheimer rather than the decision to fight Oppenheimer.
